# calculate longitude and latitude from topleft static google map

Tags: google-maps, static, latitude-longitude

I use a static map (image) from google in a mobile phone app. What i have is: the longitude-latitude data from the center (of the image), the size of image, the zoomlevel. 
How can i calculate the longitude-latitude data of the top-left (or any other place) of the image?

Answer (score 0):

You need to compute the lat/lon from a range/bearing calculation (see destination point from distance and bearing given here: http://www.movable-type.co.uk/scripts/latlong.html).  The zoom level will give you the range part.  For the bearing part, is the map north up?  If it is, then the bearing for the upper left will be 315 degrees (360 - 45).  If you don't know if the map is north up, then you will need another lat/lon point.

Comment: Do you know how to convert the zoomlevel in distance? I only find a calculation that uses 2 points to calculate the distance and i only have the center. I get the bearing part ;)

Comment: How is the zoom level specified?